# Android Studio closely cropped PNG drawable has big vertical margins

Tags: android, png, vertical-alignment, crop, pad

Noob here. I have a drawable PNG that is cropped around just the image. There is no vertical white space. When I overlay it on the parent blank vertical margins are added: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTTpk.jpg]

I want the PNG to display without those margins.

In my main activity I'm using

```
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.avalogo);
```

and in my xml I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/avalogo"
        android:padding="5px"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried everything and read much. No joy. I'm using a Samsung S6. TIA.

Comment: Have you tried adjustViewBounds set to true?

Comment: I just did. Thank you, Pedro. Works like a champ.